# Matrix identity involving trace

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I am asked to prove

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial \alpha}(\log(\det(C)))=tr\left(C^{-1}\frac{\partial C}{\partial \alpha}\right).$$

$C$ is an invertible  matrix whose entries are functions of $\alpha$. I get that the left hand side is the sum of logs of the eigenvalues. I have no clue how to proceed with RHS.

Comment: This result is known as [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi's_formula). Although the presentation is overly complicated, there's a proof in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Using the chain rule one [finds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233187/compute-the-derivative-of-the-log-of-the-determinant-of-a-with-respect-to-a/1351191#1351191) the derivative $[d_A(\log\det A)](H)=\operatorname{trace}(A^{-1}H)$. Using the chain rule a level deeper we have
$$[d_t(\log\det A_t)](\tau)=\operatorname{trace}\left(A_t^{-1}\;dA_t(\tau)\right)$$ denote $A_t^\prime$ the matrix of $dA_t$ and take the auxiliary argument $\tau$ out of the trace, then you have for the derivative map itself:
$$d_t(\log\det A_t)=\operatorname{trace}\left(A_t^{-1}\;A_t^\prime\right)$$

Comment: related? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493137/prove-frac-partial-rmlnx-partial-x-2x-1-rmdiagx-1