# Differential of determinant of metric tensor

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $(g_{ij})$  be the fundamental tensor of the Finsler metric $F$, that is
$g_{ij}(x,y) := \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^{2}F^{2}}{\partial y^{i}\partial y^{j}}$.

$$D\Big(\log \big(\sqrt{\det (g_{ij})}\big) \Big)=\frac{1}{2}g^{ij}Dg_{ij}.$$

**My Question:** Why $D(\det(g_{ij})) = D(g_{ij})$?

Answer (score 2):

Use [this, for example,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233187/compute-the-derivative-of-the-log-of-the-determinant-of-a-with-respect-to-a/1351191#1351191) to show that $[d_A(\log\det A)](H)=\operatorname{trace}(A^{-1}H)$ which hopefully agrees with your RHS if you put $g=A$, $Dg=H$, and use the expression for the inverse of metric tensor and the trace of product.